# Meteor and cloud services

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am thinking of learning meteor, but one thing that I haven't been able to get my head around is, how does cloud services behave with Meteor?

1. For example, I used https://orchestrate.io/ as 'database as a service' for one of my project. What if I want to do the same with my meteor project? Call I use orchestrate's methods for CRUD operations instead of the usual meteor-mongo way and expect the app to run normally, i.e., reactivily?
2. Another conceptual problem I am facing is, let's say I also decide to make an android app from the web app using meteor's android SDK. Will the databases be connected? This is the reason I thought of using a dbaas because I couldn't understand how would the android and web app share database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You will not be able to use meteor out of box with your dbaas. There is [work](https://www.meteor.com/livequery) being done to enable the use of other databases.
2. If the data between the web app and the mobile app is shared, there will be one database on your server. The mobile app will subscribe to the subset of the data in the database the same way the web app does. [Here is](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-meteor-publications-and-subscriptions/) more on how publications and subscriptions work.

Comment: If I use meteor deploy blablabla.meteor.com, my app becomes live, so does the database. Now if I do meteor build android, and run the app, will it be connecting to the database I made live by deploying?

Comment: Yes, when you run your app you will point it to an [existing mongo instance](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#user-content-how-do-i-hook-into-an-existing-running-mongodb-instance).